# How to convert SQL column null value to 0 and varchar to decimal in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports

I need to convert a SQL column which is in `varchar` datatype to `decimal` and the null values to 0. This is my code to convert `varchar` to `decimal`:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)),
    CAST(credit as DECIMAL(9,2)),
    sum_accname,
    sum_date, 
    sum_description
FROM 
    sum_balance
```

I need to convert debit and credit column null values to zero. How to insert the null value converting part to this code?

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)),0) as debit,
    COALESCE(CAST(credit as DECIMAL(9,2)),0) as credit,
    sum_accname,
    sum_date, 
    sum_description
FROM 
    sum_balance
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**COALESCE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349(v=sql.105).aspx) function to fetch NOT NULL values.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(COALESCE(debit, '0') AS DECIMAL(9,2)),
    CAST(COALESCE(credit, '0') AS DECIMAL(9,2)),
    sum_accname,
    sum_date, 
    sum_description
FROM 
    sum_balance;
```

Comment: this is giving an error : 'COALESCSE' is not a recognized built-in function name

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT 
    CAST(isnull(debit ,0) as DECIMAL(9,2)),
    CAST(isnull(credit,0) as DECIMAL(9,2)),
    sum_accname,
    sum_date, 
    sum_description
FROM 
    sum_balance
```

Comment: @Ganesh_Develkar this is working, but while i am using this query on a calculation its not displaying minus values (e.g.: -65000.00) all minus value are displaying 0

Comment: @user3844217 i think those values are null look at this `select CAST(isnull(-65000.00 ,0) as DECIMAL(9,2))`

Answer (score 0):

improved formatting,for sql server there is option for isnull.......
the query should be like this

```
SELECT isnull(CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)),0), 
isnull(CAST(credit as DECIMAL(9,2)),0), sum_accname, sum_date, sum_description
FROM sum_balance
```