# I am getting Incorrect syntax in this SQL CASE statmenet

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get results based on the following SQL statement. It gives me the error "Incorrect syntax near '>' ". If Saleflag is 1 then show results with SalePrice between 25-50 else show results with Price between 25-50.

```
Select
    (
        CASE
            when Saleflag = 1 then (
                cast(SalePrice as Decimal) >= '25'
                and cast(SalePrice as Decimal) <= '50'
            )
            Else (
                cast(Price as Decimal) >= '25'
                and cast(Price as Decimal) <= '50'
            )
        End as Price
    )
from
    Table
```

Comment: Claiming that `CASE` should be used in a WHERE clause, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/_Ce0MTLJ

Comment: A [mcve] would make this question much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CASE statement most definitely contains incorrect syntax. You should consult the documentation of the DBMS you are using.
However, I don't think CASE is what you want. I believe it is the following:

```sql
select *
  from TABLE
 where (Saleflag=1 and cast(SalePrice as Decimal) between 25 and 50)
    or (Saleflag!=1 and cast(Price as Decimal) between 25 and 50)
```

Comment: Your code seems to work but with one error. "Error converting data type varchar to numeric". SalePrice and Price both are varchar data types.

Comment: I am using MS SQL server 2017 or later, Saleflag is tinyint.

Comment: @bob24 does this help? [How to convert SQL column null value to 0 and varchar to decimal in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793006/how-to-convert-sql-column-null-value-to-0-and-varchar-to-decimal-in-sql-query)

Comment: @bob24 new [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LL-2fRyp) also works.

Answer (score 0):

CASE is an expression returnig a scalar. You can use it in WHERE clause

```
select *
from yourtable
where cast(case Saleflag when 1 then SalePrice else Price end as Decimal) between 25 and 50
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use the case in the where clause with out the parentehsis

```
Select
*
from Table1
WHERE CASE when Saleflag=1 then 
      (cast(SalePrice as Decimal)>='25' and cast(SalePrice as Decimal)<='50') 
      Else (cast(Price as Decimal)>='25' and cast(Price as Decimal)<='50') 
      End
```